# Contact Form 7 - Send attachment to submitter?

Tags: plugin-contact-form-7

I have installed the Contact Form 7 plugin on my WP 3.2.1 instance.

I have setup a [contact form](http://www.dekho.com.au/demorequest/) for users to request evaluations.

This is all working fine, but I was hoping that when they submitted a request, I could ping them an email with an attached product brochure.

I have it currently setup like this:

[image]

I have tried using [file-691] where 691 is the id of the uploaded media in the media gallery.

Both do not seem to work.
**What is the correct way to achieve this?**

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the feature you are trying to use is not meant to be used this way. It is in fact meant to give the submitter the option to upload a file that is send with his mail message.

I don't think such a feature is available for contact form 7

Answer (score 0):

CF7 won't work that way. What you're trying to do needs to be set up at the server or email client level, not at the application level in WP.

Set up an email auto-responder on your email server or in your email client.

Answer (score 0):

Try email-before-download used with download monitor plugin. These integrate with CF7 beautifully and all you need to do is select ATTACHMENT to be sent as an email instead of an inline download link. Works beautifully.

Comment: Try reformatting your answer with more specifics.

Comment: @aly22, could you point me to the right source "email-before-download"

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for my bad english and my even more worse PHP skills.

You can use email-before-download but... didn't got it working like i wanted.
I tried a little bit of code and i think this is working. not the finest way, but you can use the link to the file within the attachment field in the admin-gui. Just enter there something like "wp-content/uploads/2013/05/File.pdf" (without the quotes) instead of "[file-1234]" and put the following code into your `functions.php`

```
function mycustom_cf_before_action(&$wpcf7_data) {
    global $mailcounter;
    $mailcounter = 0;
    if ((!empty($wpcf7_data->mail['attachments'])) and (!(0 === strpos($wpcf7_data->mail['attachments'], '['))) ) {
        global $cmail1;
        $cmail1 = '';
        $cmail1 = $wpcf7_data->mail['attachments'];
    }
    if ((!empty($wpcf7_data->mail_2['attachments'])) and (!(0 === strpos($wpcf7_data->mail_2['attachments'], '['))) ) {
        global $cmail2;
        $cmail2 = '';
        $cmail2 = $wpcf7_data->mail_2['attachments'];
    }
}
add_action('wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'mycustom_cf_before_action',1);

function mycustom_wpcf7_mail_components($components){
    global $cmail1;
    global $cmail2;
    global $mailcounter;

    if (($mailcounter == 0) and (!empty($cmail1)) and (empty($components['attachments']))) {
          $components['attachments'][] = $cmail1;
    }
    if (($mailcounter == 1) and (!empty($cmail2)) and (empty($components['attachments']))) {
          $components['attachments'][] = $cmail2;
    }
    $mailcounter = $mailcounter + 1;
    return $components;
}

add_filter( 'wpcf7_mail_components', 'mycustom_wpcf7_mail_components' );
```

The first function checks if there are "static" attachments. so anything that doesn't start with `[` or is empty

The second function is adding the static attachment when sending. Tried to use the "uploaded_files" but then the attachments are deleted. Since the Components part is the same for mail1 and mail2 you have to count somehow. Thats the reason for `$mailcounter`. `$cmail1` and `$cmail2` is to get the links to the attachments into the components-part. CF7 doesn't care anymore about the original contact form data at this point. so this was the only solution I saw at this point.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work anymore on version 5.4. however, you can use this instead `add_filter( 'wpcf7_mail_components', function($components, $form = null, $mail = null) { $components['attachments'][] = 'PATH_TO_FILE.pdf'; return $components; }, 100, 3 );`

Answer (score -3):

I believe this is the plugin referred to: https://wordpress.org/plugins/email-before-download/